# flutter: search data from firestore with conditions

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, I'm trying to fetch data in such a with certain conditions.

I have a collection that has certain information including the current `user ID` - `"UID"`, and the `documentID` for that collection is the user ID. Not all users will have this collection by the way. However, if a user wants to have this collection, I want Firebase to first check if the user has this collection (obviously using the docID). If the user does not have this collection, then a `TextField` is provided.
However, if the user has this collection but a `field` in this collection is equal to something, say "ACTIVE", it should return a `Text()`. If the field is anything else, it should return the `TextField`. Any help?

I have tried the following codes:

```
final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
 
StreamBuilder( stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("collectionName")
            .doc(uid)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot)
            {
             final status == snapshot.data?["FieldName"]
             if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.exists && status == "Active") {
            return 
                child: Text(""); 
          }
          else return TextField();
            }
```

With this, I get this message on my screen where the user has no collection. But with the user that has the collection, it returns what I expect.

[image]

I also tried

```
final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

StreamBuilder( stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("collectionName")
                .where("UID", isEqualTo: uid) //The "UID" is stored in the collection with the current user ID.
                .where("FieldName", isEqualTo: "Active")
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot)
                {if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return 
                    child: Text(""); 
              }
              else return TextField();
                }
```

This returns this `Text()` in both cases where a user has the collection and a user does not have the collection.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a screenshot of a document in the Firestore console/web UI that you expect the query to return?

Comment: I'm not expecting the query to return anything from the database. I only want it to check if the conditions are satisfied. If the query has data, with the condition provided, then a constant like Text("has data") should be shown. Else a TextField should be shown. I don't think those ones are really necessary here, are they?

Comment: It's only the UI that changes depending on the condition. I'm not actually trying to retrieve the actual info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this code may help.**

```
final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collectionName").doc(uid).snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      // While the data is loading, you can show a loading indicator.
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }

    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
    }

    if (!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.data!.exists) {
     // Handle the case when there is no data.
     return Text("Document does not exist or data is empty");
     }

    final data = snapshot.data?.data();
    final status = data?["FieldName"];

    if (data != null && status == "Active") {
      return Text("Document exists and status is Active");
    } else {
      return TextField();
    }
  },
)
```

Comment: With you "f inal status = data?["fieldName"] " I don't think the code there is correct. It's giving error. By the way I changed that part to " final status = snapshot.data?["fieldName"] " and then continued with the loggics but still it's giving me the same thing as in the photo when the there is no data

Comment: Ohh, can you please try again because I have edited the code.

Comment: I tried the edited one and it worked. Although I had to make some alterations to it. I didn't add the "final data = snapshot.data?.data();" to it. Instead I went straight to " final status = snapshot.data?["fieldName"] ". Also I remove the "snapshot.connectionState" part because in my TextField I'm using google places and predictions and it keeps loading anytime I type a letter. So I removed that part. Thanks anyway. That helped